# How to set a js property in getDerivedStateFromProps?

Tags: reactjs

Hi how can I set a property in `static getDerivedStateFromProps` function , `this`inside `static getDerivedStateFromProps` in `undefined`

```
import _ from 'lodash'
class SomeClass extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.someArray = []
 }
 static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
     if (!_.isEqual(props.data, state.prevData)) {
      this.someArray = 'somevalue'  // how to set this variable in static function
      return {data: props.data, prevData: state.data }
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: getDerivedStateFromProps is static method and this is not accesible there. You should use componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){

} to update any instance variable.

Comment: I think you are misusing `getDerivedStateFromProps`
Read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) again.
In this case you should use `componentDidUpdate`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
     if (!_.isEqual(this.props.data, this.state.prevData)) {
      this.someArray = 'somevalue'  // how to set this variable in static function
      this.setState({
        data: this.props.data, prevData: this.state.data 
      })
     }
 }
```

But before doing this you can read through this

[Link to derived state blog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)